# How to pass input parameter to AWS Glue Map.apply function

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, distributed-system, aws-glue-spark

I am working on an AWS Glue job where I have a function `"some_function"` that I want to apply on DynamicFrame `dy_f`, but I also want to pass an input param to some_function.

```
Map.apply(frame=products_combination, f=search)
```

where some_function's definition is:

```
some_function(record, k)
```

What I've tried so far:
Works:

```
Map.apply(frame=products_combination, f=search) ##provided i'm not taking k as input in some_function def as well
```

What is giving error:

```
Map.apply(frame=products_combination, f=search(k=10))
```

This returns "TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'record'"

How can I pass a parameter to Map.apply function? I have gone through the documentation [here] but couldn't find my solution there.[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used Spark udf instead of DynamicFrame.Map.apply. Worked for me.

Comment: This requires you to leave the dynamicframe guardrails. any resolution that doesn't require to you use a dataframe?

Answer (score 3):

You can always pass in additional parameters with lambda:

```
Map.apply(frame=products_combination, f=lambda record: search(record, k=10))
```